# Generar una salida estetica en los resultados de un while de triple opcion

Tags: php, mysql, while

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
if ($row['afiliacion']=='BASICO'){
 $l = $limite_basico;
} else if ($row['afiliacion']=='AVANZADO') {
 $l = $limite_avanzado;
} else {
  $l = $limite_vip;
 }

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM monto LIMIT $limite_base, $l ";
$resultadosql = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$num_datos = mysqli_num_rows($resultadosql);
while ($rowsql=mysqli_fetch_row($resultadosql)){
  if ($num_datos ==1)
  {
    $montos_permitidos = $montos_permitidos .  $rowsql[1] . " Bs.";
 }
    else if ($num_datos > 1)
    {
       $montos_permitidos = $montos_permitidos .  $rowsql[1] . " Bs., ";
    }

    $num_datos--;
}
```

El resultado que obtengo es segun el plan:

```
Plan Basico $montos_permitidos = 1 Bs.
Plan Avanzado $montos_permitidos = 1 Bs, 2 Bs, 3 Bs.
Plan Vip $montos_permitidos = 1 Bs, 2 Bs, 3 Bs, 4 Bs.
```

y quisiera saber como puedo implementar para que que el resultado en mi salida sea de la siguiente forma:

```
Plan Basico $montos_permitidos = 1 Bs.
Plan Avanzado $montos_permitidos = 1 Bs, 2 Bs y 3 Bs.
Plan Vip $montos_permitidos = 1 Bs, 2 Bs, 3 Bs y 4 Bs.
```

Es decir que antes del ultimo resultado me coloque una `y` para marcar el final.

Comment: Incluye el SQL de la tabla monto con esos datos para poder enviarte la solución depurada

Comment: Gracias, ya con la respuesta que me indicaron he logrado solucionar, pero la estructura de la tabla montos es sencilla una columna de id y una columna de montos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($rowsql=mysqli_fetch_row($resultadosql)){
  if ($num_datos ==1)
  {
    $montos_permitidos = $montos_permitidos .  $rowsql[1] . " Bs.";
  }
  else if ($num_datos ==2)
  {
    $montos_permitidos = $montos_permitidos .  $rowsql[1] . " Bs y";
  }
  else if ($num_datos > 2)
  {
    $montos_permitidos = $montos_permitidos .  $rowsql[1] . " Bs., ";
  }
  $num_datos--;
}
```

Hay que agregarle el control para el caso que resten 2 resultados y solo poner  "," cuando es mayor a 2

No lo probe pero espero que te sirva. Saludos